# The threads are not sharing the same data variable

Tags: java, multithreading

I'm new to Java. My teacher gave me a homework on multithreading in which there are two threads Example and Example1. 
Example makes changes to a thread, and Example1 reads it.
But when I'm implementing the Example1 thread is not working properly.

Example Thread :

```
public class Example extends Thread {
    public int[] array = {2,1,0,5,9};
    public void run(){
        for(int i=0; i<array.length;i++){
            array[i] = array[i]+i;
            System.out.println(getName()+" : "+array[i]);
        }
    }
}
```

Example1 Thread :

```
public class Example1 extends Example implements Runnable {

    @Override
    public void run(){
        for(int i=0;i<array.length;i++){
            System.out.println(getName()+" : "+array[i]);
        }
    }
}
```

The main :

```
public class TestExample {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Example t1 = new Example();
        t1.setName("t1");
        t1.start();

        Example1 obj = new Example1();
        Thread t2 = new Thread(obj);
        t2.setName("t2");
        t2.start();
    }

}
```

and the output is :

```
t1 : 2
t1 : 2
t1 : 2
t1 : 8
t1 : 13
Thread-1 : 2
Thread-1 : 1
Thread-1 : 0
Thread-1 : 5
Thread-1 : 9
```

Thread Example1 is unable to read the changed values in int[] array even when Example has already made changes to the int[] array.
What could be the problem and how to rectify it?

Comment: You are using two separate instances. So there is no shared variable anywhere. Also, those two classes are strange. For one, any class that inherits from `Thread` also implements `Runnable` by default. And since `Example1` inherits from `Example` which inherits from `Thread`, then by definition it's also `Runnable`. Are you sure these are the classes given to you by your teacher?

Comment: When I'm removing the implementation from Example1 thread, it still gives me the same result and still not reading the int[] array.

Comment: Removing the implementation won't change that. There is *no* shared variable. You have one instance of `Example` you created with `new`. You have another instance of `Example1` you created with `new`. Each of those instances has its own copy of `array`. They are not sharing the same `array`. Perhaps you should show us the original assignment you got from your teacher, word for word.

Comment: if you pass the same reference to an array in your main into the constructors of your Example class you could share the same data that way.

Answer (score 0):

just make int[] array static.

```
public static int[] array = {2,1,0,5,9};
```

output :

```
t1 : 2
t1 : 2
t1 : 2
t1 : 8
t1 : 13
t2 : 2
t2 : 2
t2 : 2
t2 : 8
t2 : 13
```

Answer (score 0):

I think your issue here is misunderstanding the concept of instantiation.

you have an array living on the object itself so each time you instantiate a different array is created inside of that new object.

this is different than if something is marked "static" which will force it to have one instance.

so you have two options, use a separate static item to reference which will be shared between all instances

OR

pass around the array or some data structure containing the array between your threaded objects so you are actually manipulating it rather than working on two different arrays created when the threaded objects are created

Answer (score 0):

You can use **static**, but the better OO way: make that an instance field, like:

```
public class Example extends Thread {
  private int[] array;
  public Example(int[] array) {
    this.array = array;
  }
...
```

Similarly for Example2; and then you go in your main:

```
 int[] array = { 1, 2, 3, 4 };
 Example ex1 = new Example(array);
```

In other words: your two classes are working on two **different** array objects. Simply hand the **same** object to your two threads!

And just to be sure: when you add this code; you might still see **surprising** result - as you have **two** threads dealing with the same array; possibly in parallel. So be prepared for all kinds of unexpected outputs!